# Azure running db sproc via code throws "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user"

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I have a dotnet core application running on azure. There are several pages interact with the db and those render fine and without error; however there is one page which executes a stored procedure in the db, which is failing.

After some initial troubleshooting I noticed the error being thrown is "Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user *username*"

Using sql server management studio, I used the application connection string - along with the username and password for *username* - to connect to the azure db and was able to execute the stored procedure without error - So I'm not sure why I'm getting this problem.

Observations:

1. Can view pages which fetch data from the database via plain EFcore
   code
2. Page which runs stored procedure fails - "An error occured while processing your request" - This was found to be "Exception:
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for *username*"
3. Can connect to the remote azure DB using sql server management studio and execute the stored procedure using the user account
   *username*
4. Works fine in development with a local SQL server database (of
   course)
5. Configuring my local dev environment to use the remote Azure DB (connecting with *username*) throws the same error at the same page

Based on this it seems the problem lies with configuration of the remote DB. Given that *username* can execute the stored procedure through SSMS -this should mean that it has the right permissions to execute that stored procedure.

Any ideas on what I should check next or how I can go about resolving this will be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Do you see the failures against the expected database in sys.event_log?

Comment: not seeing any failures in sys.event_log

Comment: Is this all being done from the same IP address?

Comment: yup, all from the same IP address

Comment: "not seeing any failures in sys.event_log " then debug the app locally and double check you're connecting to the correct SQL Server.

Comment: I can reconfigure the local instance to connect to either my local machine or the remote azure DB. Once I publish the app to azure it's configured to speak only to the azure DB. If I configure my my local machine to use my local DB on my machine, it works - including the page running the sproc; if I configure it to use the remote db, I can see data that only exists remotely, and the page which runs the stored procedure fails.

Comment: I re-wrote my code to use the FromSql extension instead of SqlCommand and it works now. With SqlCommand I need to specify the connection string to use - In my case I used `Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString`  - However using FromSql I don't need to specify the connection string. I'm not sure what the exact issue was, but everything works now.